# I can't update chart range in Excel

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to create a macro for every time a data is inserted in the last line of Excel the chart automatically updates the selected range to include all the data present in the sheet but when the program executes an error occurs, can someone help me?

Code:

```
Public Sub Chart_Update()

Dim k As Long

k = Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row

Range("B2:B" & k & ",E2:E" & k & ",I2:I" & k & ",K2:K" & k).Select
ActiveChart.SetSourceData Source:=Range("AC_Offset_Registers!B2:B" & k & ",E2:E" & k & ",I2:I" & k & ", K2:K" & k)

ActiveWorkbook.Close SaveChanges:=True

End Sub
```

Error:

[image: Error Info]

[image: Error Code]

Answer (score 0):

Change `Range("AC_Offset_Registers!B2:B" …` into `ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("AC_Offset_Registers").Range("B2:B" …` and remove the entire line before (you don't need to `.Select`).

You might benefit from reading
[How to avoid using Select in Excel VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba).

Also make sure you specify a worksheet for `Cells` in the same way `ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("AC_Offset_Registers").Cells`

```
Public Sub Chart_Update()
    Dim ws As Worksheet    
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("AC_Offset_Registers")

    Dim k As Long
    k = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
    
    ActiveChart.SetSourceData Source:=ws.Range("B2:B" & k & ",E2:E" & k & ",I2:I" & k & ", K2:K" & k)
    
    ThisWorkbook.Close SaveChanges:=True
End Sub
```

Comment: Hello friend, thanks for the reply, but the error remains even after changing the code as you said

Comment: @KhallP because you did not do what I did. Read carefully again. You did something else.

Comment: friend I checked and it's the same :(, check the post

Comment: It is not. Make sure you copy and paste my code.

Comment: Then make sure to replace `ActiveChart` with a static reference to your chart.

Comment: I copied your code and pasted it and it still doesn't work...

Comment: I told you you need to make sure to replace `ActiveChart` with a static reference to your chart.

Comment: how can i know the name of my chart?

Comment: @KhallP Actually you named it so you should know. When you select the chart, its name is in the left of the formula bar.

Comment: Can you check the new response I made to my post?

Answer (score 0):

I found that the name of my chart is "Gráfico 2" but when I run the program I get a "Subscript out of range" error, could you tell me if the code below is right?

Public Sub Chart_Update()

```
Dim ws As Worksheet, ws_2 As Worksheet, k As Long

Set ws = Sheets("AC_Offset_Registers")
Set ws_2 = Sheets("Gráfico")
k = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row

Charts("Gráfico 2").SetSourceData Source:=ws_2.Range("B2:B" & k & ",E2:E" & k & ",I2:I" & k & ",K2:K" & k)

ThisWorkbook.Close SaveChanges:=True
```

End Sub

Comment: Please only use your original question to add code. Answers that do not provide a solution will be deleted by the community. • Try `Worksheets("Gráfico").ChartObjects("Gráfico 2").Chart.SetSourceData Source:=ws.Range("B2:B" & k & ",E2:E" & k & ",I2:I" & k & ",K2:K" & k)`